# WPF: после анимации появления окна прозрачность не управляется из кода

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, анимация, прозрачность

В MainWindows.xaml я добавил такой код, чтобы у окна было плавное появление при запуске:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

Однако теперь у меня перестала регулироваться прозрачность, заданная в MainWindow.xaml.cs для других случаев, например здесь при перетаскивании окна:

```
 private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
       if (isDragging && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
       {
           myWindow.Opacity = 0.85;
```

Окно теперь всегда имеет 100% прозрачность. Замена "myWindow.Opacity" на "Grid.Opacity" тоже не влияет на результат.

Answer (score 1):

Решил через добавление свойства `FillBehavior="Stop"`:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.3" FillBehavior="Stop"/>
```